# Pass value from component A to B after component A initialize value completed

Tags: angular

I use service pass value from component A to B

**Servie A**

```
public data: // is a object 
public processData() {
    // process about seconds and set value to data variable
}
```

**Component B**

```
private data; // is object
constructor(private servieA: ServieA) {} 
ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this.servieA.data;
}
```

But my code not work. Please help me thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Subject Observable provided by rxjs

**Common Service**

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
export class CommonService {
  dataChanged = new Subject<any>();
}
```

**Component A**

```
export class AComponent implements onInit {
  constructor(commonService: CommonService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    //pass data after some activity
    this.commonService.datachanged.next(somedata);
  }
}
```

**Component B**

```
export class BComponent implements onInit {
  constructor(commonService: CommonService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    //listen to data changes from component A
    this.commonService.dataChanged
      .subscribe(newData => {
         //do your stuff with the new data provided by component A
      })
  }
}
```